# Trouble with Global Send Keys Event/ VB SendKeys

Tags: blueprism

I am currently working with one application that requires to press Numpad Enter (Keycode 13 Location: 3) in specific situations. Regular Enter (Keycode 13 Location 0) does not work.

I have tried to use:
Global Send Keys: with {ENTER}
Global Send Keys Event: with {ENTER}, ~, {RETURN}
VB code stage with

```
     My.Computer.Keyboard.SendKeys("{ENTER}", True)
```

They all seems to Press KeyCode 13 Location 0. And I need to press Keycode 13 Location 3 specifically.

Does anyone have an idea how to create in BluePrism functionality to press KeyCode 13 location 3 button?

Answer (score 1):

Allright I managed to solve it!
Thanks to: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEQ5Y_5.9.0/com.ibm.pcomm.doc/books/html/host_access08.htm

```
Dim autECLPSObj As Object
autECLPSObj = CreateObject("PCOMM.autECLPS")
autECLPSObj.SetConnectionByName ("A")
autECLPSObj.SendKeys ("[enter]")
```

Basically for PCOMM there is a list of mnemonic keys, you can send with this method.
Fun part is, there no need for any PCOMM dll. The only thing you need is a namespace: Microsoft.VisualBasic.Interaction
It works without any issue and you can use all of the other autECLPS type of object!